# why doesnt' it use the parameter in this raw sql?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using this code:

```
SqlParameter pNombreUsuario = new SqlParameter("NombreUsuario", paramNombreUsuario);
object[] parametros = new object[] { pNombreUsuario };

string passwordDB = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select password from Personal where NombreUsuario = @NombreUsuario", parametros)
                             .SingleOrDefault<string>();
```

but the query that is sent to the database is:

```
select password from Personal where NombreUsuario = @NombreUsuario
```

Why the parameter with the username name is not used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696545%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) indicate that you should send an array of object values rather than `SqlParameter` objects.

E.g.

```
string passwordDB = dbContext.Database
                             .SqlQuery<string>("select password from Personal where NombreUsuario = @p0", paramNombreUsuario)
                             .SingleOrDefault<string>();
```

Does that work for you?

Edit: I misread the docs. Try this:

```
string passwordDB = dbContext.Database
                             .SqlQuery<string>(
                                 "select password from Personal where NombreUsuario = @NombreUsuario", 
                                 new SqlParameter("NombreUsuario", paramNombreUsuario))
                             .SingleOrDefault<string>();
```

Comment: I this case the query that is sent to the database is: "select password from Personal where NombreUsuario = @p0", it seems the same result.

Comment: With the second option i get: "select password from Personal where NombreUsuario = @NombreUsuario"

Comment: How are you determining what gets sent to the DB? What you're seeing is correct - EF will wrap this in a call to `sp_executesql` under the hood with the parameters specified.

Comment: I see that in cisual studio when I debug the code. If I use paramters I don't get any result but if I don't use parameters I get one rsult, so this makes thinking that the problem is that is not send the correct information. Perhaps I am missing something.

Comment: Is this in the debug console? If so, can you update your question with that output?